# Can I share photos to Facebook without downloading my contacts?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I would like to share photos on facebook. However, it is required to sign in, after which all facebook contacts will be downloaded.

Would it be possible to avoid downloading contacts from facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can turn this setting off in: Settings > Facebook > Contacts On/Off

Comment: I do not see it.